# Python Removing duplicates 3 at a time

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates

I am looking for some help here, I have a list which is exactly this

**list like this: [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]**

**wanted result: [1, 5, 10, 10, 8, 8]**

I have tried every possible way by iterating through the list 3 at a time and replacing only every third.

```
''.join([List[i] for i in range(len(List) - 1) if List[i + 1] != XX[i]] + [List[-1]])
```

I just can't get my head around it is there some python wizard who can do this?

Thanks

Comment: what is expected result for such list = [1,1,1,1,1] ? It

Comment: In this case, a simple slice is all you need: `[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8][::3]`.

Comment: Will there always be duplicates? What would `[1,2,3]` return?

Comment: [1,1,1,1,1] does not exists and there are always 3 pairs of the same value

Comment: nice oneliner - just nobody here who can read it at first sight. Did you really write it this way?

Comment: Does [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5] exist?

Answer (score 7):

try

```
foo = [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
print foo[::3]
```

This is called "list slicing".  What this practically does is it prints out every third argument of your list starting from the first.  This article [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) explains the concept more thoroughly.

Comment: that worked!! python is amazing Thanks

Comment: You could accept the answer if you are happy with it.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
lst    = [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
output = []

skip = 0
for idx, x in enumerate(lst):
    if skip:
        skip = skip - 1
        continue

    if (idx + 2) <= len(lst):
        if lst[idx] == lst[idx+1] and lst[idx] == lst[idx+2]:
            output.append(lst[idx])
            skip = skip + 2
    else:
        output.append(lst[idx])

print output
```